# ( ! ) Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in C:\wamp\www\final p4\tabla_borrar.php on line 20

Tags: php, mysqli

hola tengo un problema quiero seleccionar en una case de datos una columna por medido de un formulario y la seleccionada imprimirla

```
introducir el código aquí<html><head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/principal.css" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
<form action="tabla_borrar.php" method="POST">
<p>Buscar Para borrar Por:</p>
<p>nombre <input type="radio" name="Buscar" value="nombre"/></p>
<p>precio<input type="radio" name="Buscar" value ="precio"/></p>
<p>id<input type="radio" name="Buscar" value="id"/></p>
<input type="reset" value="Borrar"> <input type="submit"><br><br><br>
<a href="index.php">DEVOLVER A EL FORMULARIO </a>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

codigo de imprimir la tabla

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/principal.css" type="text/css">
<?php
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","");
mysqli_select_db($link,"db1") or die ("Error al conectar a la base de         
Datos");
$buscar = $_POST['Buscar'];
$query=mysqli_query($link, "SELECT ".$buscar.",codigo FROM tal1 ");
?>
<html>
<body>
<h1>Eliminacion de Productos</h1>
<form method="POST" >
<table border="1" bgcolor="gray">
<tr>
<th colspan="2">Eliminar</th>




</tr>
<?php
while($arreglo=mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
?>
<tr>
<th><input type="checkbox" name="casilla[]" value="<?php echo                  
$arreglo['codigo'] ; ?>"></th>
<th><?php echo $arreglo[$buscar] ;?></th>
</tr>
<?php
}
?>
</table>
<input type="submit" value="Eliminar">
</form>

<a href="index.php">DEVOLVER A EL FORMULARIO </a>
</body>
</table>
```

Comment: perdon si hay errores es mi primera pregunta

Comment: Te doy la bienvenida. Para poder ayudarte mejor cambia las imágenes por el texto mismo del código. Las imágenes no se pueden ver bien en dispositivos pequeños y si se quieren hacer pruebas con el código habría que re-escribirlo todo, lo cual es harto difícil. Como podrás comprender, el texto del código es de mucho mayor utilidad en estos casos. [Pulsa aquí para editar la pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/210607/edit) y hacer los cambios indicados. Gracias.

Comment: ya lo corregí ...

Comment: Parece que hay algún problema con la consulta. Conviene siempre controlar su ejecución, por ejemplo: `if (!$query=mysqli_query($link, "SELECT ".$buscar.",codigo FROM tal1 ")) { echo "Hubo un error con la consulta: ".mysqli_error($link); }else{ //el resto de tu código  cerrando el if con esta llave--> }` Ahí te dirá el error que hay. Ten en cuenta que se ha abierto un `if` nuevo y que debes cerrarlo en el lugar correcto.

Answer (score 0):

1. la query no deberia ser asi:
2. el error que te manda es porque no esta devolviendo nada la query!

```
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","");
mysqli_select_db($link,"db1") or die ("Error al conectar a la base de         
Datos");
// previene sql injection
$buscar = filter_var($_POST['Buscar'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

    // como lo tienes esta mal jamas deberias hacerlo
    // suponiendo que tu campo se llama busca seria asi:

    $query=mysqli_query($link, "SELECT busca, codigo FROM tal1 where buscar='".$buscar."' ");
    if(!$query){ die("no hubo resultados sorry");}
    ?>
    <html>
    <body>
    <h1>Eliminacion de Productos</h1>
    <form method="POST" >
    <table border="1" bgcolor="gray">
    <tr>
    <th colspan="2">Eliminar</th>




    </tr>
    <?php
    while($arreglo=mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
    ?>
    <tr>
    <th><input type="checkbox" name="casilla[]" value="<?php echo                  
    $arreglo['codigo'] ; ?>"></th>
    <th><?php echo $arreglo[$buscar] ;?></th>
    </tr>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
    </table>
    <input type="submit" value="Eliminar">
    </form>

    <a href="index.php">DEVOLVER A EL FORMULARIO </a>
    </body>
    </table>
```